# Get list of objects from S3 bucket using Minio in .Net

Tags: asp.net, .net, amazon-s3, minio, ionos

I'm using Minio .Net SDK (v 3.1.13) in a web app to get buckets and files storage at IONOS Cloud Storage. It uses the AWS S3 specifications.
I can check is a bucket exists and its contents, but just only the first time after compilation. Next times i get empty results.

S3ObjectStorage.cs

````
{
    private MinioClient _minioClient;
    public S3ObjectStorage(string key, string secret, string region, string httpsEndPoint) {
        _minioClient = new MinioClient(httpsEndPoint, key, secret, region).WithSSL();
    }
    public async Task<bool> BucketExists(string bucketName) {
            bool found = await _minioClient.BucketExistsAsync(bucketName);
            return found;
    }

    public async Task<string> ListFiles(string bucketName, string path)
    {
        if (!await BucketExists(bucketName)) throw new Exception($"Buckect {bucketName} doesn't exists");
        List<object> files = new List<object>();
        IObservable<Item> observable = _minioClient.ListObjectsAsync(bucketName, path);
        IDisposable subscription = observable.Subscribe(
            item => files.Add(new { item.Key, item.Size })
            //,ex => //Console.WriteLine($"OnError: {ex}")
        );
        return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(files);
    }
}```

TestS3.aspx.vb
```Private Async Function List(bucketName As String, path As String) As Task
        Dim cs As New S3ObjectStorage(CS_KEY, CS_SECRET, CS_REGION, HTTPS_ENDPOINT)
        Dim result As String = Await cs.ListFiles(bucketName, path)
        Dim objects = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(result)
        Me.rptObjetos.DataSource = objects
        Me.rptObjetos.DataBind()
        Me.lblPath.Text = $"{bucketName}>>{path} ({objects.Count} - {result})"
    End Function```

Thanks a lot.
````

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got it!

```
using System.Reactive.Linq;
    
public async Task<string> ListFiles(string bucketName, string path)
{
    if (!await BucketExists(bucketName)) throw new Exception($"Buckect {bucketName} doesn't exists");
    var files = await _minioClient.ListObjectsAsync(bucketName, path).ToList();
    return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(files);
}
```